# Matching observations in the same table

Tags: sas

I was wondering if SAS can match observations in the same table based on multiple matching conditions and then tag them. 
For instance I want observations which matches on age and gender but only differs based on if they like star wars or not.

This is the data I have

```
   age  gender  Like star wars  Location
    34  male         1            US
    36  female       0            UK
    24  female       1            AU
    45  female       1            US
    34  male         0            CH
    36  female       1            US
    57  female       0            US
```

Want

```
>    age    gender  Like star wars  Location    Match
>     34    male         1            US         Yes
>     36    female       0            UK         Yes
>     24    female       1            AU         No
>     45    female       1            US         No
>     34    male         0            CH         Yes
>     36    female       1            US         Yes
>     57    female       0            US         No
```

Comment: What have you tried ?  Can you explain the rules for `Match`, particularly the cases of `34-male` and `36-female`.

Comment: I am struggling with PROC SQL, group by age and gender, but don't know how to assign a tag for the results. The match for 34-male is made since they have the same age and gender, but differ on liking to star wars, irrespective of their location

Comment: So is the match because one likes and one does not like ? If both liked or both disliked would the match be 'No' ?  What it there were three observations with `34-male` -- how would Match be assigned based on the 'Like star wars' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the data you have by age and gender, then the "matches" will be grouped together. The non-matches can easily be detected with `first.` and `last.` processing. Rows that are both `first.` and `last.` do not have a match.

```
proc sort data=have;
by age gender;

data want;
set have;
by age gender;
match = ifc(first.age and last.age, 'No', 'Yes');
run;
```

[image]